# Communicate via SPI in Android

Tags: android, spi

Currently I'm looking for a solution to communicate via SPI in Android. I installed the NDK on my system and used the native classes to communicate with the GPIO´s (/sys/class/gpio/gpioxx/value) on my Wandboard. It works fine. So the principle to use the NDK or C code in Android is clear for me. Unfortunately I can't find any SPI devices /dev/… . I only find I²C devices. Can somebody tell me, if android basically offers SPI? And if it is possible, where I can find the device? Can I communicate in the same way like with Linux?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

*This is an answer to a very old question but it could still be valuable for someone else*

Often by default `/dev/spidev0.0` is not enabled. It must be enabled both in the kernel during build time and device tree during runtime.

The first step is to change linux kernel build configuration to enable spidev by adding

```
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
```

And in the device tree (one of the dts files) add a `spidev` leaf to the spi device you wish to map to connect to.

*This is an example for hikey960 and spi3 on the high-speed connector other boards will be slightly different*

```
&spi3 {
    /* On High speed expansion */
    label = "HS-SPI1";
    status = "okay";
    spi-cpol=<0>;
    spidev@1 {
       spi-max-frequency = <5000000>;
        compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
        pl022,com-mode = <2>;
    }
};
```

You will be able to read and write to the device `/dev/spidev0.0` with a simple `cat > /dev/spidev0.0` and `cat </dev/spidev0.0` but [`ioctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) must be used for more complex options e.g. reconfiguration of speed, change polarity, and full duplex write/read.